# Having trouble adding schema code into my email build

Tags: google-schemas

I am having difficulty adding Schema code into my email build - when I test the email in Gmail nothing is displaying.

I have tried testing my email and am not seeing the Schema information.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<script type="application/ld+json">
[{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "Organization",

// WARNING: Before sending email, either point the logo
// at your own image or delete the logo annotation.
//
// If showing a logo, we recommend using an https URL.
// It's not a requirement today, but may be in the future.
"logo": "http://media.bobsdiscountfurniture.com/7843/Miscellaneous/little    -bob-profile.jpg"
},{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "EmailMessage",

// Alternative subject line.
"subjectLine": "It's Two for Tuesday!"
},{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "DiscountOffer",

    "description": "Two items - one great price!",

"discountCode": "",
"availabilityStarts": "2019-06-09T06:51:45-07:00",
"availabilityEnds": "2019-06-12T06:51:45-07:00"
},{
// Promotion card with single image.
// We recommend using an https URL.// 
// Sample image is 538x138, 3.9 aspect ratio
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "PromotionCard",
"image": "https://productimages.mybobs.com/20052909/20052909_hero_wide.pn    g"
}]
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Email Body</p>
<p>Line 2</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am hoping to have my Schema code display in my test email proof so that I can send to Google in order to be authorized to incorporate Schema coding into my emails on a regular basis moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the official documentation regarding Email Markup and do a [self test by sending email to yourself](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/testing-your-schema). Please also remember that for the content of your sample email, it is highly suggested to use a production setup same with your schema code.